# not well-formed in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I am using click listeners in my document ready function. Every click listener have a lengthy code in it. For an easiness i have created a separate java script file and place click listener in that file and in my document ready i loaded that script. Now Mozilla is giving my this error

> not well-formed

Here is the exact code which i am using

```
// ChangePasswordProcess.js File

$("#changePasswordButton").click(function (){
  if($("#newPassword").val() != $("#confirmNewPassword").val()){
      alert('Your new password did not matched');
      return false;
  }else if($("#newPassword").val() == '' || $("#confirmNewPassword").val() == ''){
      alert('Please enter new password');
      return false;
  }else{
      alert('Password changed successfully');
  }
});
```

Here is the way i am loading above java script file in my document ready

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
   $(function () {
  $.getScript('js/ChangePasswordProcess.js');
  });
});
```

Actually i want to keep document ready file very simple and short by dividing its code among different java script files. If anyone can have any alternate solution for doing this ?

[image]

Comment: What does the 'not well formed' error point to? There should be more information given than that. Also note that you don't need to nest document.ready handlers as you are in your second code snippet.

Comment: I suspect path is wrong and you are getting some html being returned. Inspect the actual request itself in browser dev tools network and see what the response body contains

Comment: Actually function is working properly but i am concerning about console warning. And as per Rory McCrossan i think i need to handel i click events in document ready thats why i nested it under document ready

Comment: Is that all you have in your `ChangePasswordProcess.js` file what you posted in your question?

Comment: Yes this is all in my `ChangePasswordProcess.js`

Comment: Then it is a really bad idea to split code like that, as it will get you an extra http request for almost nothing and that is not good. ... To maintain a good performance for your users, you should go the other way around, merging as much as possible, not breaking it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Mozilla that reports "content-type" as "application/xml" for a file retrieved using the `file://` protocol from local disk via XMLHttpRequests. The error "not well-formed" would indicate the javascript content is not XML, but operation of script supports the view that FireFox recovers successfully. My *guess* is that it's the same problem as [Bug 409230](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=409230)

Confirmation of buggy behavior comes from the error disappearing when serving the same page and javascript file via `http://` using a Node/Express server running on `localhost`. Node/express correctly reports the content of the javascript file as "application/javascript" and there is no error message.

**Test HTML** (with simplified ready function):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Not well-formed</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="lib/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
      $.getScript('js/ChangePasswordProcess.js'); 
 });
</script>
</head><body>
password: <input id="newPassword" type="text"><br>
confirm: <input id="confirmNewPassword" type="text"><br>
<button type="button" id="changePasswordButton">change</button>
</body></html>
```

**Script**
In the unminified `jquery-2.2.1.js file`, at around line 8114, add

```
console.log("content-type: " + jqXHR.getResponseHeader( "Content-Type" ));
```

to report the response content-type. `js/ChangePasswordProcess.js` file unchanged from the OP.